# How do i go about Weight panting and animating this model?

Tags: animation, weight-painting

I am new to rigging. I want to export a rocket launcher model with a shooting animation. The model and the flaps should be animated. I want to do it with bones.

1. Do i just Keep all the bones connected or are the 6 flap bones just childs to the main bone?
2. Should the flaps be separate from the rocket model or is keeping it all 1 model better?
3. If keeping them all 1 model makes it easier, how do i weight paint each flap to each bone separately?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEIZB.jpg)
[image]

Im still having one issue, the armature, bone and vertex group are named the same and its weight painted with a value of 1 but i cant seem to tell the bone what vertex group its suppose to be assigned to. To clarify the bones are all separate and not parented or child to anything. [image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Blender.se. I edited your post for brevity. If I have removed any important details, please edit them back in.

Comment: (1) There is no need to connect the bones, disconnected child-parent relation have no drawbacks. (2) It is up to your personal preference. If you use a single model you use weight painting. If you use multiple model you can use parenting. (I would suggest weight painting.) (3) Manually create [vertex groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html#assigning-a-vertex-group), select the appropriate vertices and assign the to the group with a weight of one.

Comment: This way of assigning weights is best for your rigid model. Weightpainting is better suited for organic weights with smooth transitions. In your case you just want to have a group of vertices assigned to one vertex group 100%. With the vertex group panel you will have good control.